# Android - Advertisement ID (AD_ID) permission for adult but not for child due to google play policy

Tags: android-permissions, google-play-console, adjust-android

I have removed the AD_ID permission from out application due to Google play famility policy vialation because it got rejected. I am using AdjustSDK that includes by default ad_id permission in manifest hence merged manifest also contained this permission that's why I added in manifest `<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID tools:node="remove"/>`  and this line completly removed this permission from project and my app got approved. But now I want ad_id permission for Adult but not for child. How can I manage this from manifest? please suggest on this. Some blog suggested to create a new screen for age concent then initialize the Adjust sdk but If I removed that ad_id permission tag mentioned earlier , google reviewer in static analysis, will reject my app. Thanks in advance for your help